# How Django runs tests parallelly?

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I'm curious how django runs test parallelly with
`python manage.py test --parallel`.
Would someone please explain the what happens under the hood and and the the life cycle of test with an example.

Answer (score -1):

Runs tests in separate parallel processes. Since modern processors have multiple cores, this allows running tests significantly faster.

Relevant [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-test-parallel).

Comment: Thanks, for responding but my question is more about what happens under the hood how django make it possible using multiproccessing.